# Rails render pass parameter by calling a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, render

I am using rails render method in my `haml` to view partials, & now I want to pass a `ctrl` variable to the partial,

```
= render 'path', variable: '$ctrl.methodName()'
```

But this cannot be rendered, I am getting haml compilation error. Do anyone have idea how can use method return variables in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Use `locals` parameter:

```
= render 'path', locals: { variable: '$ctrl.methodName()' }
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables